# Using the half angle formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Find $\sin\frac { x }{ 2 }, \cos\frac { x }{ 2 }$, and $\tan\frac { x }{ 2 }$ from $\sin x=\frac { 3 }{ 5 } ,\quad 0°<x<90°$

What I did:

$$\sin\frac { x }{ 2 } =\sqrt { \frac { 1-\frac { 4 }{ 5 }  }{ 2 }  } =\sqrt { 10 } $$

$$\cos\frac { x }{ 2 } =\sqrt { \frac { 1+\frac { 4 }{ 5 }  }{ 2 }  } =\sqrt { \frac { 9 }{ 10 }  } =\frac { 3 }{ \sqrt { 10 }  } $$

$$\tan\frac { x }{ 2 } =\frac { \frac { 3 }{ 5 }  }{ 1+\frac { 4 }{ 5 }  } =\frac { \frac { 3 }{ 5 }  }{ \frac { 9 }{ 5 }  } =\frac { 1 }{ 3 } $$

The last one seems to be the only one that corresponds to the correct answer. The first two are wrong and I can't seem to find where I went wrong.

Comment: What are the correct answers?

Comment: $$\frac { \sqrt { 10 }  }{ 10 } ,\quad \frac { 3\sqrt { 10 }  }{ 10 } ,\quad \frac { 1 }{ 3 } $$

Comment: $\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}} = \frac{3\sqrt{10}}{10}$

Comment: they just rationalized the denominator?

Comment: The mistake in the first one : it is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}=\frac{\sqrt{10}}{10}$

Answer (score 2):

As $0<\dfrac x2<45^\circ\implies$ all the trigonometric ratios $>0$

$$\sin^2\frac x2=\frac{1-\cos x}2=\cdots=\frac1{10}\implies\sin\frac x2=+\frac1{\sqrt{10}}=\frac{\sqrt{10}}{10}$$

Similarly for $\cos\dfrac x2$